# ¿Cómo desuscribir un conjuntos de peticiones unidas con combineLatest?

Tags: angularjs-2.0, observable

Normalmente suelo agrupar muchas peticiones que se subscriben a varios servicio **http** dentro de un controlador mediante `Observable.combineLatest` ya que no importa el orden que se ejecuten las mismas, la duda es si cuando desuscribo el observable en `ngOnDestroy` también se desuscriben los elementos que agrupo o como se procede en este caso. Dejo el siguiente código para explicar la idea:

normalmente para una única peticion separada hago:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.proyectos$ = this.proyectosService.getByCodigo(this.subproyecto.CodProyecto).subscribe(response => {
        //hacer algo
    }):
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.proyectos$.unsubscribe();
}
```

pero cuando son varios prefiero este modo, ya que ninguno depende del otro.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.globalSub$ = Observable.combineLatest(
        this.proyectosService.getByCodigo(this.subproyecto.CodProyecto),
        this.datosDiagnosticoService.all(),
        this.resultadosEsperadoService.all(),
        this.subproyectoMultimediaService.bySubproyecto(this.subproyecto.CodSubProyecto),
        this.opcionesDatosDiagnosticoService.all(),
        this.datosDiagnosticoSubproyectoService.bySubproyecto(this.subproyecto.CodSubProyecto),
        this.opcionesResultadosEsperadoService.all(),
        this.resultadosEsperadoSubproyectoService.bySubproyecto(this.subproyecto.CodSubProyecto),
    ).subscribe(([
        _proyecto,
        _datosDiagnostico,
        _resultadosEsperados,
        _documentos,
        _opcionesDiagnostico,
        _datosDiagSubproyecto,
        _opcionesResultadosEsperados,
        _resultadosEspSubproyecto
    ]) => { //codigo no relevante }
}


ngOnDestroy() {
    this.globalSub$.unsubscribe();
}
```

¿Este procedimiento para el segundo caso así desuscribir todos los elementos es el correcto o como se procede?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### La respuesta es sí...

Pero hay un par de cosas que me gustaría mencionar al respecto.

**1.- Un sólo Observable**

Efectivamente `this.globalSub$` es un conjunto de `Observable`s combinados en uno solo, donde el valor que se emite corresponden a una colección con los últimos valores de cada `Observable`. Si haces un `console.log` de `this.globalSub$`, probablemente vas a ver algo como esto:

```
Subscriber {
    closed: false,
    destination: SafeSubscriber,
    isStopped: false,
    syncErrorThrowable: false,
    syncErrorThrown: false,
    syncErrorValue: null,
    _parent: null,
    _parents: null,
    _subscriptions: Array(1)
}
```

Por ende al ejecutar el método `unsubscribe()` en el `Subscriber`, todos los `Observables` que componen la suscripción son removidos. Si inspeccionas nuevamente la suscripción el output es distinto:

```
Subscriber {
    closed: true,
    destination: SafeSubscriber,
    isStopped: true,
    syncErrorThrowable: false,
    syncErrorThrown: false,
    syncErrorValue: null,
    _parent: null,
    _parents: null,
    _subscriptions: null
}
```

Como puedes ver la propiedad `_subscriptions` es `null`. Lo importante es que finalmente estás combinando un montón de Observables en un solo Observable, y por ende te tienes que preocupar de gestionar sólo una suscripción.

**2.- No es necesario llamar unsubscribe()**

No es necesario llamar a `unsubscribe()` de forma explícita porque si el `Observable` está definido como una propiedad de la clase, al destruirse el componente automáticamente se elimina la suscripción, por lo tanto no deberías tener problemas de memory leak.

Te recomiendo leer [este artículo](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87) de Ben Lesh con más información al respecto.

**3. Extra**

Finalmente ¿es necesario que combines todos los Observables en uno sólo? Lo importante es que esto se acomode a tu caso de uso, porque ahora lo que estás haciendo es esperar a que todos los servicios que consumes se resuelvan para poder obtener la información de cada uno de ellos. En la mayoría de las ocasiones, este no es el mejor de los escenarios, pero claro, todo depende de lo que necesites hacer.

Igualmente cada vez que se vuelva a ejecutar uno, emitirás la cadena completa de últimos valores. Si cada Observable se ejecuta una sola vez, quizás te convendría utilizar otro operador como `forkJoin`.

Comment: Los combino porque mientras cargan los datos se bloquea la pantalla y para mi preferente esperar a que cargue el ultimo antes de dejar la posibilidad de hacer algo al usuario. Quería de suscribirlos a todo porque llego un momento que el memory leak me mato estuve días leyendo por todos casos tratando de encontrar la solución al problema, por subscribir tantos servicios sin hacer nada después. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo me aclaro varias cosas, revisare lo de `forkJoin`.

Comment: ¿Y esos servicios los consultas al cargar el componente o una vez que ya fue iniciado? Porque podrías utilizar un resolve en el primer caso

Comment: Al cargar el componente, aunque algunos se recargan después por una actualización de los datos, pero no son todos.